# django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "dashboard_menugroup" does not exist

Tags: python, django

I have these models:

```
# coding:utf-8
from django.db import models
from django.utils.text import slugify
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

class MenuGroup(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('nome'), max_length=30, blank=False, primary_key=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(_('slug'), blank=True, null=True, db_index=True)

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'dashboard'
        verbose_name = _('gruppo')
        verbose_name_plural = _('gruppi')
        ordering = ('name',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

   def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super(MenuGroup, self).save(*args, **kwargs)


class MenuProduct(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    ingredients = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    price = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, default=0.0)
    group = models.ForeignKey(MenuGroup, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'dashboard'
        verbose_name = _('prodotto')
        verbose_name_plural = _('prodotti')
        ordering = ('name',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Order(models.Model):
    price = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, default=0.0)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'dashboard'
        verbose_name = _('ordine')
        verbose_name_plural = _('ordini')
        ordering = ('date',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.date


class OrderHasMenuProduct(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(MenuProduct, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

suppose that we want to reset our database and we launch the following commands:

```
$ find . -path "*/migrations/*.py" -not -name "__init__.py" -delete
$ find . -path "*/migrations/*.pyc"  -delete
```

And the we launch the commands to recreate the schema:

```
$ python manage.py makemigrations
```

And i obtain the follow output:
Migrations for 'dashboard':

dashboard/migrations/0001_initial.py
    - Create model MenuGroup
    - Create model MenuProduct
    - Create model Order
    - Create model OrderHasMenuProduct

Then i launch:

```
$ python manage.py migrate
```

And i obtain the follow output:

Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.

Using the Django API for the database i insert some records into the `MenuGroup` table, then i open a view to display all of them.

My View:

```
from django.views.generic.list import ListView
class MenuView(ListView):
    model = MenuGroup
    context_object_name = "all_menu_groups"
    template_name = 'dashboard/menu.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(MenuView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['page_title'] = _('Menu')
        return context
```

And when i try to dispatch the page i obtain the following error:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "dashboard_menugroup" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT (1) AS "a" FROM "dashboard_menugroup" WHERE "dashboar...
                           ^
```

Answer (score 1):

Its not enough to remove the migration files. You also have to delete the database.

Edit: Actually there are some migration tables which you have to delete. You can use undocumented Django model for doing so: `MigrationRecorder.Migration.objects.all().delete()`

I have a management command package for this case but its not well tested to use for production.

Comment: let me the time to try